# Short story with strange relic on moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I know I've had a fair few of these questions recently, but I just can't remember their titles!

So, this one kind of reminded me of *2001: A Space Odyssey*. It has aliens that left a special artifact on the moon which broadcasts signals into space. Then, something happens that causes those signals to stop and people go to investigate, I think. It was also once mentioned that the aliens used special human technology to put the artifact there. Final detail: I'm pretty sure the object was in the shape of a pyramid or a triangular prism. 60% sure that this is Asimov, Bradbury, or one of the other Sci-Fi giants.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be thinking of [The Sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sentinel_(short_story)), a short story by [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke).

The alien artifact in that story was a translucent Tetrahedron, which matches your description.

This short story provided the inspiration for a [rather well known film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)).

Comment: The plot description in the question is kinda the inverse of Sentinel. My first thought as well, though.

Comment: This is absolutely right! I didn't know it was the inspiration for A Space Odyssey. I just thought they were kinda similar.